# Unable to launch click events in backboneJS over typescript

Tags: backbone.js, typescript

This is a Backbone project written in Typescript. I am unable to launch a click event for a checkbox with BackboneJS. Here's the code:

//backbone code

```
events = {
        "click .add-new-question-box": "clickEvent"
    };

    clickEvent(){
        console.log(this.model.get("question"))
        alert(this.model.get("question"));
    }
```

//html template

```
<input id="<%= typeId %>" type="checkbox" class = "add-new-question-box">
```

The template renders just fine, but when I click the checkbox, I dont see the event getting called.

---

**
**Update**
**

I've replicated this problem in another instance where I'm using lambda, but its still nt working. Here's the full code:

```
function getNewDiv(id:string){
    return "<div id = \"" + id + "\"></div>"
}

class TestView extends Backbone.View{

    events = {
        "click #testDiv" : "start"
    }

    start = ()=>{
        console.log(this.model.get("question"))
        alert(this.model.get("question"));
    }

    constructor(options?){
        super(options);
    }

    render(){
        $root.html(getNewDiv("testDiv"));
        $("#testDiv").css("height", 100).css("width", 100).css("background-color", "blue");
        console.log("Rendered");
        return this;
    }
}

new TestView().render();
```

The rendering happens just fine. The click handler is still not being called. Here is the console output.

```
Rendered
```

Comment: Do you have more of the JavaScript you could show? What you've shown isn't enough. In fact, it doesn't look correct out of context.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is `this` might be incorrect. Try using a lambda:

```
   clickEvent = ()=>{
        console.log(this.model.get("question"))
        alert(this.model.get("question"));
    }
```

Comment: Its written in Typescript, not javascript. So "this" should be fine.

Comment: lambda's exist in typescript not javascript :) Anyways the reason is that `this` might still become wrong e.g. if you pass a member function of a class around, `this` is taken from the calling context (which might not be the class) unless you capture it with a closure (which lambda syntax will do for you)

Comment: I've made the fix you said. I've also replicated the problem in a different piece of the code, where it still does not work. Please see updated question. This should make it easier for you to solve it. I appreciate your help.